# Changing multiple upload text

Tags: 2010, file-upload

Just wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to change the text SharePoint 2010 presents when you select the upload multiple documents. Currently it says: “Drag Files and Folders here” I would like to change it to “Drag Files here” . Our business case is that our users are uploading folders to document sets which is a “No No” in SharePoint 2010.  I realise changing the text won't stop them dragging folders in but at least it won't be seen to encouraging them to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Upload.aspx is an application page because it is served up from the _Layouts virtual directory of the server instead of the content database. All Application pages are bound to use Application.master as master page. You simply can't change Application.master or any application pages.

Therefore, your best is to attach/insert some jQuery/Javascript using **Custom Action** and `ScriptLink`, which will change the text for you.

Comment: I'm afraid he's right. I was looking if it were possible to edit the upload.aspx page in the _Layouts folder. But that does not seem feasible.

Comment: It's not recommended to change files in 14 hive but it becomes pretty much a trivial task using Javascript/jQuery.